# Flask: getting url_prefix for blueprint in view

Tags: python, flask

I have a blueprint with one view. I would like to get `url_prefix` of blueprint inside view. Unfortunately `test.url_prefix` returns `None`. Is there any other way?

```
app.register_blueprint(test_blueprint, url_prefix = "/test")

@test.route("/task", methods=["GET"])
def task_view(user):
    task_url = test.url_prefix + "/task" # test.url_prefix is None ??
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

In Flask the route path of the current view is contained in the **url_rule.rule** subproperty of the **request** variable.

So you can do the following:

```
from flask import request

...

test_blueprint = Blueprint('test', __name__, url_prefix='/test')

...

@test_blueprint.route("/task", methods=["GET"])
def task_view(user):
    task_url = request.url_rule.rule

....

app.register_blueprint(test_blueprint)
```

The value of task_url will be:

```
/test/task
```

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

```
from flask import Blueprint


admin_panel = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')


@admin_panel.route('/')
def index():
    url_prefix=admin_panel.name
    print(url_prefix)
    pass
```